# What is the default directory of android apps XML?

Tags: android, andengine

im using this code, and I think this code is for desktop apps

```
String filepath = "C:\\assets\\level\\\levelStatus.lvl";

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

I was wondering if is this okay, or if not I think i need the directory of where will the XML files of my app are installed. Because I have tons of XML files in my assets folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like that

```
 InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("test.xml");
```

if your file have inner folder in assets folder then try this way

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open(file:///android_asset/myfoldername/test.xml);
```

or try like this

```
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("myfoldername/test.xml");
```

Comment: so I just put this, and my XML files will readable as long as its in the assets folder? btw its an folder within a folder :)

Answer (score 2):

This will take you to the root of you assets folder:

```
file:///android_assets/
```